# How to get certain text from html tag on python?

Tags: python

I'm making a Python md5 decryptor from an API, but the problem is the API is sending back an HTML feedback. How do I get the text between the `<font color=green>` ?

```
{"error":0,"msg":"<font color=blue><b>Live</b></font><font color=green>Jumpman#23</font> | [MD5 Decrypt] .S/C0D3"}
```

Comment: Use an HTML parser such as bs4 (BeatifulSoup)

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using an HTML parser as [Beautiful Soup](https://github.com/waylan/beautifulsoup):

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> d = {"error":0,"msg":"<font color=blue><b>Live</b></font><font color=green>Jumpman#23</font> | [MD5 Decrypt] .S/C0D3"}
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(d['msg'], 'html.parser')
>>> soup.font.attrs
{'color': 'blue'}
```

You will get a dict that contains key, value pars as attribute name, value.

#### Update

To get the text `"Jumpman#23"`

```
>>> soup.findAll("font", {"color": "green"})[0].contents[0]
'Jumpman#23'
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Comment: @LimitedBrainCells, would you mind validating the answer please if this was useful?

Answer (score 0):

If you know the target text will be exactly `<font color=green>`, then you can use simple string operations:

```
msg = "<font color=blue><b>Live</b></font><font color=green>Jumpman#23</font> | [MD5 Decrypt] .S/C0D3"
start_pattern = "<font color=green>"
stop_pattern = "<"
start_index = msg.find(start_pattern) + len(start_pattern)
stop_index = start_index + msg[start_index:].find(stop_pattern)
print msg[start_index:stop_index]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use  `bs4` and an adjacent sibling combinator for font tag

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
s = {"error":0,"msg":"<font color=blue><b>Live</b></font><font color=green>Jumpman#23</font> | [MD5 Decrypt] .S/C0D3"}
soup = bs(s['msg'], 'lxml')
data =  soup.select_one('font + font').text
print(data)
```

Comment: is the font colour important or does this need to apply more generally to between ?